# Start Thrift Server Error File not found: /tmp/hive/

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax, thrift

i have access to a cluster that has the following error when we try to start thrift server with this command:

`dse -u my_usser -p my_password spark-sql-thriftserver start`

After run that command, the folling message appears:

`# starting org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2, logging to /root/spark-thrift-server/spark-root-org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2-1-node3.domain.com.out`

When i show the output of that file, the error is:

> WARN  2017-12-29 01:44:01,875 org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some configuration may not take effect.
>   ERROR 2017-12-29 01:44:05,379 org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper: Failed to start or submit Spark application
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.NoSuchFileException: File not found: /tmp/hive/
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.(HiveClientImpl.scala:189) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:43) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.metadataHive(HiveSessionState.scala:43) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLEnv$.init(SparkSQLEnv.scala:62) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:81) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]

I have create manually that directory but that is not working :(

Comment: Did you check file system permissions?

Comment: Yes i check the permissions on /tmp/hive i change the owner to be cassandra, and the group is cassandra too. The permissions was 777. I update the error to give mor information

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ? if Yes how ? I'm going through same issue

Comment: shamely I was not able to fix it. Neither creating the directory.

Comment: Did you find any work around to get through it ? I'am trying to submit my job on dse spark and getting this error. If you can help how you find alternate solution.

Comment: I am having similar issue... any solution?